# QuickFIX number of threads to handle a fix message

Tags: c++, multithreading, quickfix

I notice in the code fragment below that in QuickFIX, the threadID is always always the same in that whatever thread id `fromApp` outputs equals the thread id of  `MarketDataIncrementalRefresh`. But I also notice that the threads from invocation of `fromApp` to another `fromApp` can vary, meaning that QuickFIX is throwing the message onto a different (threadpool?) thread.

My questions are, (all more or less related)

1. If I don't get off the thread, am I blocking QF from grabbing
   another message?
2. Is there a parameter that allows me to control how many threads QF
   uses to manage incoming messages?
3. It seems that if this "number of threads to use" value is high enough, then there is no reason
   to handle (parse etc) the message received in one the virtual methods, e.g.,
   MarketDataIncrementalRefresh in yet another thread?

---

```
void MyApplication::fromApp( const FIX::Message& message, const` FIX::SessionID& sessionID )
    throw( /*FIX::FieldNotFound,*/ FIX::IncorrectDataFormat, FIX::IncorrectTagValue, FIX::UnsupportedMessageType )
    {
        //std::cout << std::endl << "IN: " << message << "\n";

        try
        {
            std::cout << "fromApp " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
            crack( message, sessionID );
        }
        catch(std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::cout << "crack exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";
        }
    }

void MyApplication::onMessage
    (const FIX44::MarketDataIncrementalRefresh& message, const FIX::SessionID& fsid)
    {
        std::cout << "MarketDataIncrementalRefresh " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: The answer to (1) is yes, absolutely.  Do not do expensive operations in the callbacks.  This is true for all QF ports.  (I don't know enough about QF/C++ to answer the other ones.)

Comment: Actually the more I think about it the more I realize it doesn't matter. If you have a MT application on a single symbol, you will have to write synchronization code in your callbacks, which means your code is serialized anyway and those cores are blocked. If you don't do MT in your callback, then the internal QF message queue acts as your serialization scheme. I think it is just a trade-off where you go from a fat pipe to  skinny one. But six of one half a dozen of another...MT code is really meant for things that truly can run in parallel.

Comment: May not completely answser your question, it's a good referrence worth notice from the community: http://quickfix.13857.n7.nabble.com/ThreadedSocketInitiator-vs-SocketInitiator-tt4672.html#a4679

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are two ways to instantiate an Initiator:

```
FIX::SocketInitiator initiator( application, storeFactory, settings);
```

or

```
FIX::ThreadedSocketInitiator initiator( application, storeFactory, settings);
```

But this appears to handle the case where one thread handles multiple sessions or several threads handle different sessions. My question has to do with if the thread that cracks the message and the thread that handles the communications/receiving of the message are the same in these QF threading models. So not quite the same thing I think. In other words, once the message has traveled further into the application.

I have also seen code like this:

```
new SocketAcceptor(3, new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 3, 1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000)));
```